# Is there a standard way to migrate Kafka Consumers?

Tags: apache-kafka, migration

There is a Consumer A consuming from Topic A.
Consumer A is going to be deprecated (as it belongs to a different team and they dont handle the use case anymore). It is not possible to just change the ownership of the component to our team as we already have a Consumer B. Consumer B currently listens to Topic B. We want to leverage the Consumer B to read from Topic A as well.

So, we want to migrate the business logic in Consumer A to Consumer B.
Before going ahead with the full fledged migration, we want to validate the logic for a small part of the traffic.

Is there a standard way of migrating business logic from Consumer A to Consumer B ?
For the small part of traffic, is it possible to just process the traffic in Consumer B ?

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal world, your business logic code should be separated from the consumer code. Because your business logic most likely going to outlive your broker technology's life span. If you are in that ideal world, you can route a subset of the messages to the new business logic library. Say for example if you decided to route 10% of the traffic, do message offset % 10 = 0 then route it to the new logic. If you are not in an ideal world, you can try manual partition assignment and take only those messages coming into a specific partition. Try [this](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#manualassignment).